# How to (Right click + Move mouse to the Left) in MACBOOK PRO

Tags: mac, mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

I am using Genymotion and playing game: Clash of Clan. To Zoom in I need to : Right click + Move mouse to the Left. How can i do this Macbook pro retina display 15 inch. I know that  tapping with two fingers means right click. I tapped with two fingers & without pulling them back i moved them to right of screen but nothing seems to happen. I also used my third finger to move right while tapped with 2 fingers but neither of these two tricks worked.

Comment: Try Control/click or Cmd/click [system uses ctrl, some games use cmd]

Answer (score 1):

1. Press down on the trackpad with two fingers to click the trackpad.
2. Keep the fingers held down and move them left.
3. Release fingers.

[image]